# use classpath from existing manifest in ant build

Tags: java, ant, classpath, manifest

I am developing a Java EE web application with some module jars and some web modules. I'm using eclipse as development platform. In a Java EE web application the libraries and dependencies are written down in the manifest files. Eclipse parses these files and the build (and deployment to a server) in eclipse works well.

Now on a continious integration system Ant will do the build process and no eclipse is present there. So for the Ant-build I want to use the same information from the manifest because I do not want to copy the classpath and dependency informations.

There are many modules in my app so it is important to resolve the build order.
I do not want to edit the classpath, I only want to read it to build my project. I know, there is an Ant task to create or update the manifest file but I want to got the reversed way.

Does anybody know an Ant task to read the manifest for creating a classpath?